# rails and pdfkit can not generate pdf from controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdfkit

I have a problem generating PDF file with pdf_kit gem.
If i run those commands in the my app console (RAILS_ENV=production rails c):

```
kit = PDFKit.new(html, :page_size => 'Letter')
file = kit.to_file('./demo.pdf')
```

I can see the pdf file correctly generated, but if I try the same thing on action controller, in this way:

```
kit = PDFKit.new("ciao")
kit.to_file('/root/app/bidimal/demo1.pdf')
```

I get this error in production.log

```
RuntimeError (command failed: "/root/.rbenv/shims/wkhtmltopdf" "--encoding" "UTF-8" "--page-size" "A4" "--margin-top" "0.25in" "--margin-right" "0.25in" "--margin-bottom" "0.25in" "--margin-left" "0.25in" "--quiet" "-" "/root/app/bidimal/demo1.pdf"):
  app/controllers/winners_controller.rb:69:in `invoice'
```

I've already checked the path of wkhtmltopdf by using:

```
which wkhtmltopdf
/root/.rbenv/shims/wkhtmltopdf
```

so I suppose it is correct. By the way I've this in config/initializers/pdfkit.rb

```
PDFKit.configure do |config|
  config.wkhtmltopdf = '/root/.rbenv/shims/wkhtmltopdf'
  config.default_options[:ignore_load_errors] = true
  config.default_options = {
    :encoding=>"UTF-8",
    :page_size=>"A4",
    :margin_top=>"0.25in",
    :margin_right=>"0.25in",
    :margin_bottom=>"0.25in",
    :margin_left=>"0.25in",
    :disable_smart_shrinking=>false
    }
end
```

I'm under nginx+passenger, the problem can be related somehow at any nginx settings(like processes available and so on)?
Thank you

Comment: I downloaded the correct bin from here http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/downloads/list and changed the pdfkit.rb in order to point to it. it work fine

Comment: So your problem is solved?  If so, consider posting an answer or closing the question.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I started having problems with the wkhtmltopdf-binary gem... I'm still unsure about what happened.

To fix it, I did the following:

1. I removed the wkhtmltopdf-binary gem from my gemfile
2. I also had this gem installed in my rbenv environment. I logged into the server and deleted it by doing gem uninstall wkhtmltopdf-binary
3. I installed the wkhtmltopdf executable on my system directly. (I am on ubuntu so the command for me was sudo apt-get install wkhtmltopdf)
4. I created an initializer in my rails app "config/initializers/pdfkit.rb" with the following

`PDFKit.configure do |config|
  config.wkhtmltopdf = '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf'
end`

And everthing started working again.